# Is it possible to access addEventListener options object from within callback function

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to set the addEventListener to un-attach after the first event, based on a conditional related to the event.

I want something like;

```js
var thing = document.querySelector('.thing');
thing.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if (e.pointerType === 'mouse'){
    this.addEventListener.options.once = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<a class="thing">Thing</a>
```

Comment: If you want to do it like that, why not just remove the listener?

Comment: document.body.addEventListener( 'click', () => { console.log('1') }, { once: true } );

Comment: Use `thing.removeEventListener()`. You'll need to use a named function instead of an anonymous function, since the function argument has to be the same in both calls.

Comment: You could also add/remove the class from the anchor, since the handler is attached to the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`.removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). You can do it like this:

```js
function handler(event){
  if (event.pointerType === 'mouse'){
    this.addEventListener.options.once = true;
    var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement
    targetElement.removeEventListener("click", handler);
  }
}

var thing = document.querySelector('.thing');
thing.addEventListener('click', handler);
```